# Casting a Fireball spell past an illusionary wall from Major Image

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, spellcasting, targeting, illusion

Player knew that a illusionary wall (Major Image) was fake. They wanted to centre the Fireball past the illusionary wall to catch a target that had just run thought it.

I said, they couldn't as they didn't have line of sight, although they did have line of effect.

Was my ruling correct?

Comment: Details that would help answer this question: HOW did the player know the illusionary wall is fake? What effect produced the wall? These details are *highly* relevant b/c some illusory effects specify that you can see through them once you know they're fake, and the answer absolutely depends on the situation. Illusions aren't cover unless they say they're solid, and many stop functioning as obscurement once you know they're fake.

Comment: other characters had interacted with the wall, and the target had been seen to run though it. I think the wall was a major illusion, but I will need to check.

Comment: Do you mean *Major Image?* https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Major%20Image#content

Comment: was just checking the adventure - yes Major Image

Comment: @TheFallen0ne you linked to the wrong version of the spell. https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/majorImage.htm

Comment: You say that the "player" knew the wall was an illusion. Did the character?

Comment: IIRC yes the character did at that moment.

Comment: I goofed with my answer, it was based entirely on 5e. I've deleted it. Need to pay closer attention to my tags, apparently, sorry!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### They only need line of effect to fireball

This is under the Magic rules on [aiming a spell](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#aimingASpell):

> A line of effect is a straight, unblocked path that indicates what a spell can affect. A line of effect is canceled by a solid barrier. It’s like line of sight for ranged weapons, except that **it’s not blocked by fog, darkness, and other factors that limit normal sight**.
>
> [...] You must have a clear line of effect to the point of origin of any spell you cast.

There is no requirement for a spell to have line of sight, only for line of effect. The illusion only blocked line of sight, not line of effect, because it is not a solid barrier.

[Fireball](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/fireball.htm) also does not say it requires line of sight. It is a ***area spread*** spell.

> Some spells create or summon things rather than affecting things that are already present. You must designate the location where these things are to appear, either by seeing it **or defining it** [...]
> A spread spell spreads out like a burst but can turn corners. You **select the point of origin**, and the spell spreads out a given distance in all directions.

Answer (score 8):

No, that was incorrect (assuming you were trying to stick to the official rules without involving Rule 0).

First, they had line of sight (probably):

> A successful saving throw against an illusion reveals it to be false, but a figment or phantasm remains as a translucent outline.

<sup>([Magic Overview → Illusion](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#illusion))</sup>

If they knew it was fake, they see a translucent outline, but being translucent, they can see through it.

(Technically, you don’t say *how* they knew the illusion was fake, and the rules don't detail exactly what “interaction” entails, but most tables in my experience rule anything that confirms an Illusion fake as an interaction, and that someone then automatically succeeds on the save. But it’s not totally clear under the rules, and your table may do things differently, which may mean that the character saw the full, opaque illusion even though they knew it was fake.)

Second, spells require line of *effect*, and **do not** require line of sight. (There are some exceptions where a specific spell specifically notes that it needs line of sight, but *fireball* isn’t one of them.) I can’t prove a negative, but in the Aiming A Spell rules, the only time “line of sight” appears is in the description of line of effect, which are said to be “like line of sight for ranged weapons, except that it’s not blocked by fog, darkness, and other factors that limit normal sight.” An Illusion (other than a quasi-real Shadow spell) is one of those “factors that limit normal sight.”